# How to get the true altitude in non-standard temperature using a regular barometric altimeter?

Tags: altimeter

I wondering how can we get the true altitude with non standard temperature on regular barometer altimeter, as we know that if we set Kollsman window to the current local setting the altimeter SHOULD shows the actual altitude above sea level ( True Altitude ), but if the temperature is above or below standard the indicated altitude on the altimeter will not be the same as the actual true altitude.

Comment: @ edit suggestion, OP is aware about the effect, and is asking how to get the "true altitude" as they put it.